# insert in DB php+mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, insert

i have a DB MySQL;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `obsequios` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`promocion` int(1) NOT NULL,
`dia` date NOT NULL,
`hora` time NOT NULL,
`autorizacion` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`obsequiado_a` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

php code:

```
$sql_obsequios = '"INSERT INTO `obsequios`(`promocion`, `dia`, `hora`, `autorizacion`, `obsequiado_a`) VALUES ('.$promocion.','.'"'.$date.'"'.','.'"'.$hour.'"'.','.'"'.$user_loading.'"'.','.'"'.$regalado_a.'"'.')"';
$sql_obsequios_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_obsequios);
if ($sql_obsequios_result) {
    $result_gral = true;
}else{
    $result_gral = false;
}
```

when I try to add data to the table, I get the value **return is false**.
try to see the value of $ sql_obsequiosy its value is as follows:

```
"INSERT INTO `obsequios`(`promocion`, `dia`, `hora`, `autorizacion`, `obsequiado_a`)
                                    VALUES (1,"2014-04-13","08:47:55","marcos","sergio")"
```

using phpmyadmin I have managed to successfully query. I detect what's wrong in this code

Comment: Did you try connecting to the db and executing the query? I don't see it in your code...

Answer (score 1):

Where is Your instructions to add data to DB ?

```
$sql_obsequios = ...

if ($sql_obsequios_result) ...
```

it is not the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see the difference:

```
$sql_obsequios = "
INSERT INTO `obsequios`
(`promocion`, `dia`, `hora`, `autorizacion`, `obsequiado_a`)
VALUES
('".$promocion."','".$date."','".$hour."','".$user_loading."','".$regalado_a."')";
```

Also, I dont see any call of `mysql_query()` or something to get `$sql_obsequios_result`

Comment: of course I do that, but I have not put there, but do not know what is wrong with the query, because through php it does not, but if I succeed by phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql_obsequios = "INSERT INTO `obsequios`(`promocion`, `dia`, `hora`, `autorizacion`, `obsequiado_a`) VALUES ('$promocion','$date','$hour','$user_loading','$regalado_a')";

$sql_obsequios_result = mysql_query(sql_obsequios);

if ($sql_obsequios_result) {
    $result_gral = true;
}else{
    $result_gral = false;
}
```

Comment: of course I do that, but I have not put there, but do not know what is wrong with the query, because through php it does not, but if I succeed by phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Or try:

```
$sql_obsequios = "INSERT INTO obsequios(promocion, dia, hora, autorizacion, obsequiado_a) VALUES ('.$promocion.',''.$date.'',''.$hour.'',''.$user_loading.'',''.$regalado_a.'')";

$sql_obsequios_result = mysql_query(sql_obsequios);

if ($sql_obsequios_result) {
    $result_gral = true;
}else{
    $result_gral = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but again i get false..
 this is the query with your answer:
`INSERT INTO obsequios (promocion, dia, hora, autorizacion, obsequiado_a) VALUES ('.1.',''.2014-04-13.'',''.09:18:15.'',''.marcos.'',''.Juan.'')`

 y see any point in thue query, and i propose this:
`$sql_obsequios = "INSERT INTO obsequios (promocion, dia, hora, autorizacion, obsequiado_a) VALUES ('$promocion',''$date'',''$hour'',''$user_loading'',''$regalado_a'')";`

obtain this result:
`INSERT INTO obsequios (promocion, dia, hora, autorizacion, obsequiado_a) VALUES ('1',''2014-04-13'',''09:15:44'',''marcos'',''Juan'')`

Comment: My fault last chance: "INSERT INTO obsequios(promocion, dia, hora, autorizacion, obsequiado_a) VALUES (".$promocion.",'".$date."','".$hour."','".$user_loading."','".$regalado_a."')";